# Bootsrap 4 overlapping sticky sidebar on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on design of the website that's using Bootstrap 4. I wanted to add to this sticky sidebar on the right. My general vision was to have two boxes - 1 (content) and 2 (sidebar).

I managed to place boxes correctly for devices except mobile. Then for mobile I wanted to have sidebar on top of content, so 2 on top of 1.

This part is a bit of a struggle. There is no problem in stacking them correctly. Problem is the fact, that box 2 is overlapping 1. And I am not sure how to fix this.

I have following code

```
<style>
    .content-section {
    min-height: 2000px;
  }

  .sidebar-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .make-me-sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
</style>

<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="content-section card card-body">
                <div>1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 order-first order-md-last">
            <div class="sidebar-item">
                <div class="make-me-sticky">
                    <div class="card card-body">2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see demo here:
https://www.codeply.com/go/IiDkjH70EY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <style>
    .content-section {
    min-height: 2000px;
  }

  .sidebar-item {
    position: relative; /* Change From absolute TO relative */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .make-me-sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
</style>

<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="content-section card card-body">
                <div>1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 order-first order-md-last">
            <div class="sidebar-item">
                <div class="make-me-sticky">
                    <div class="card card-body">2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```